# RobotFramework: can'f find element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

Working with RF in recent weeks I noticed a problem, which stuck me for a long time. I have constant error:

Element with locator 'XXX' (this is a template, of course) not found

Investigation of span that wanted to locate revealed, that it has some JavaScript code under it, that, from what I think, enables it dynamically.

*input bo-attr="" id="inventory-keyword" ng-attr-placeholder="{{('inventoryMode.' + {true: 'KEYWORD_DEVICE_PLACEHOLDER', false: 'KEYWORD_TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER'}[items.currentSeen == VIEWS.EQUIPEMENT]) | translate}}" ng-model="getCurrentFilters().searchString" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Name, description..."*

How to have it passed by RobotFramework?
Or maybe source of the problem is different?

There are other elements like this (with sth that appaers to be JavaScript under it), and none of it is seen by RF, except the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

From the `Javascript` code you have added to post, it seems the underlying Web Application uses `AngularJS` (I can see `ng-model` in code).

Sometimes, you cannot identify elements in `AngularJS` developed Webpage using the default ways the Selenium provides.

You can use `AngularJS` library or `ExtendedSelenium2Library` which has new ways to locate elements like model/binding etc.

Check below links for more information :

- [AngularJSLibrary](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs)
- [ExtendedSelenium2Library](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-extendedselenium2library/doc/ExtendedSelenium2Library.html)

Comment: Unfortunately RF can't see Keywords from that libraries (installed, and imported properly). 
I have error like: [ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\test.robot': Importing test library 'ExtendedSelenium2Library' failed: Module
NotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium2Library.keywords' and long traceback regarding this. 
It might be problems with them working with Selenium 3.0 that I have installed. Do you know possible solution or workaround?